# What is the precise definition of *direction* of current and of current element for a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current

The Biot–Savart law states that magnetic field due to an elemental cylindrical system through which a constant current $I$ is passing at a point $r$ distance away is given by $$d\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\frac{Id\vec{s}\times \vec{r}}{r^2}.$$
$\mu_o$ is a constant and the product $Id\vec{s}$ is called current element but what is $d\vec{s}$? It is a vector with the magnitude as the length of the element in direction of the current that flows through it. The direction of current is defined as the direction in which positive charges move. But it is a fact that in a conductor charges experience collisions with each other and atom lattices. Hence it is absurd to take the definition of the direction of the current too seriously *at least for conductors*. Hence when we say that the direction of current in a *conductor* is in this way then we mean that the positive charges tend to move in that way.
So the direction of current as defined is too vague, at least for *conductors*, to be used to define a vector like $d\vec{s}$. But in no book or article, this point is raised and discussed, so here I ask it.

Comment: $dS$ is same as $dL$. And you pointed it correctly, I think you are trying to ask that as $dL$ is very small element and in that very less amount of space the flowing electrons will collide each other and the vacancies present in the conductors as well, so you might be thinking that why those electrons does not change there direction backwards and at instant the current will be opposite to the direction at which it is flowing if we focus on the very large length due to the collisions since it's very small length so it's considerable.....

Comment: .....So let me tell you that the case you are thinking actually tends to happen but because of the strong electric field inside the conductor induce the force on the electron which we Call it as an electric force which is too strong because of this force the electrons overcomes the velocity that might be induced in the backward direction due to the collisions and hence electrons moves forward with the constant velocity which we call it as a drift velocity.

Comment: @TejasDahake Yes, that's correct; the statistical nature of heat gives random motion to electrons, but we only call it 'current' when the motion is directed, nonrandom, and the average "drift" velocity is that current.

Answer (score 3):

The variables such as the magnetic field $\vec B$, current $I$ and it’s associated direction $ \vec{ds}$ are **macroscopic quantities**. That means they are averaged over a volume that is much larger than the elements that make up the system. See the concept of [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit?wprov=sfti1) for a rigorous definition between macroscopic and microscopic quantities.

In your particular question, the current flow $I$ in the Biot-Savart law is averaged over both time and space, thereby eliminating the need to consider the fine motion of individual protons or electrons. To quote [Jackson](https://books.google.com/books/about/Classical_Electrodynamics.html?id=FOBBEAAAQBAJ):

> So far we have considered electromagnetic fields and sources in vacuum. The
> Maxwell equations (I.1b) for the electric and magnetic fields E and B can be
> thought of as equations giving the fields everywhere in space, provided all the
> sources p and J are specified. For a small number of definite sources, determi-
> nation of the fields is a tractable problem; but for macroscopic aggregates of
> matter, the solution of the equations is almost impossible. There are two aspects
> here. One is that the number of individual sources, the charged particles in every
> atom and nucleus, is prohibitively large. The other aspect is that for macroscopic
> observations the detailed behavior of the fields, with their drastic variations in
> space over atomic distances, is not relevant. What is relevant is the average of a
> field or a source over a volume large compared to the volume occupied by a
> single atom or molecule. We call such averaged quantities the macroscopic fields
> and macroscopic sources. It is shown in detail in Section 6.6 that the macroscopic
> Maxwell equations are of the form (I.la) with E and B the averaged E and B of
> the microscopic or vacuum Maxwell

-*Classical Electrodynamics*, JD Jackson 1999, pg 13.

There are situations where you *cannot* ignore these microscopic fluctuations. For example, in very sensitive electrical circuits. See the [thermal noise in electrical circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise?wprov=sfti1) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

A normal conductor is (a close approximation of) ohmic, i.e. obeys Ohm's law.   The
current density is in the direction of, and proportional to,
the electric field.   Solving for the internal field of
a shaped conductor (like, a bent wire or segment of sheet
metal) is less familiar a problem than the external field
in static electricity, but it can be done.

The chaotic nature of conduction electron collisions at room temperature is a large contributor to Ohm's law, and
determines conductivity.
At the large scale of useful current carriers,though, there
is no need to treat individual electrons or collisions.
The average motions of a fluid of mobile electrons are
all that we consider.

Comment: I completely agree with you please read my statement in the OP's post comment I think this might also be the reason and please tell me is it correct or not and is it similar to your answer in any way. And tell me if anything is wrong.

Comment: I cant quite see how that answers my question. How do we precisely define the direction of current when charges are moving chaotically?

Comment: @Osmium _"How do we precisely define the direction of current when charges are moving chaotically?"_ - you cannot "precisely". You either take the current for each charge separately (if you are interested in the behaviour of single particles), or you take the current for the collective charge for all the particles together (if you are interested in the macroscopic behaviour). The Biot-Savart law assumes that collective charge flow is constant. Note also that the current is usually much easier to detect than the movements of the individual charges.

Comment: If we cant define the direction precisely then how can we define that vector? Also, a constant current can be due to many charged particles moving chaotically.

Comment: @Osmium We don't define a different vector for all the free charges in a conductor.   We look at an average motion, of the moving charge, not of individual electrons.   In a metal, the moving charges are NOT individuals; their wavefunction overlaps multiple atoms (that's the nature of metallic bonding).