# What is the definition of direction of current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

[Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Electric_current#:%7E:text=Since%20current%20can%20be%20the,in%20which%20positive%20charges%20flow.) defines the direction of current as:

> The direction of conventional current is arbitrarily defined as the direction in which positive charges flow.

But suppose a region where there is a non-uniform electric field in some direction. Now suppose some protons are forced to move opposite to the field. What will be the direction of current in this case? Will it be in the direction of the field or opposite to it? According to the definition mentioned on Wikipedia, it should be in the opposite direction. Now suppose a proton is forced to move perpendicular to the path of the previous protons. What will be the direction of current now? What if it was moving at an angle $\not=90^o?$ It cant be answered in this case using the definition mentioned on Wikipedia. So what is the *general* definition of the direction of current? This question is related to another [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688816/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-direction-of-current-and-of-current-element) of mine.

Answer (score 2):

> So what is the general definition of the direction of current?

Current is not a vector, so it doesn’t generally have a direction. It does have a sign but that is it.

The related vector quantity is the current density. The current density is defined as $\vec J = \rho \vec v$ where $\rho$ is the charge density and $\vec v$ is the velocity of the charge. This is a proper vector.

Note that the direction of the current density is not defined based on the direction of the fields. In Ohmic materials they coincide, but not in general. So it doesn’t matter what the direction of the fields are. If the charges are moving a certain direction then that is the direction of the current density.

Now, to obtain current, you integrate the current density over a defined area such as the cross section of a wire: $$I=\int_A \vec J \cdot d\vec A$$ Then the sign of the current is defined by the direction chosen for $d\vec A$. So current can be positive or negative, but does not have a direction.

Comment: Is it worth adding some text to state that the definition in Wikipedia is a simplification when describing flow of current in a circuit versus a more general definition?

Comment: I know that it is not a vector but it does have a direction as stated in many books. What should I think about the vector $d\vec{s}$ in Biot Savart law? Thank you.

Comment: I think that saying it has a direction is misleading. It has a sign. It is either going through $d\vec A$ in the sense of the normal or in the opposite sense. But that is not a direction. Note, the quote is only talking about two opposite directions, which is consistent with a sign.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the direction of the moving charge. (current is charge moved per time).

But note that a charge carrier cannot be just "made" to move against the field..You need a field which is stronger than the initial field to do it.

Comment: i know that, of course i know that.

Comment: Suppose a proton is accelerated to very high speed and then it enters a region of the uniform field which has a field opposite to the motion of the proton. What about this case?

Comment: @Osmium in that case, the current will continue to be along with the proton, but it will experience deceleration.

Comment: Then similarly consider two such protons accelerated at a right angle as considered the main post. What will be the current direction in this case?

Comment: It will be the sum of the instantaneous charge movement.

Answer (score 0):

Related questions:

1. “What is the temperature of a single atom?”
2. “What is the density of a single atom?”
3. “What is the pressure exerted by a single atom?”
4. “What is the electric conductivity of a single atom?”
5. “What is the current of a single [charged] atom?”

In all cases the properties in question lack meaning because they are **macroscopic quantities**. That means they derive their definition by being averages over a larger system. How large is “large enough” is discussed in the concept of a [Thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit?wprov=sfti1).

I answer your question then by claiming it is not meaningful to talk of the current of a single proton, since electrical current is the average property of a larger system.

Comment: I didn't intend my question to be of the type of questions you mentioned; replace one proton with millions of protons. What about that case?